# Как получить данные(токен, пароль, логин) с AsyncStorage в react-native+expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

Делаю авторизацию и не могу получить токен из AsyncStorage 
код сохранения

```js
_storeData = async (token, phone, password) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@token', token);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@phone', phone);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('@password', password);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

считываю

```js
    _retrieveData = async () => {
        try {
          const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
          if (value !== null) {
            console.log(value);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          // Error retrieving data
          console.log('error');
        }
      };
```

при считывании вообще ничего в консоль не выходит
как получить данные из AsyncStorage? использую старый AsyncStorage чтобы с expo работал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
```

вот здесь имя надо было прописать @token а не token